# Reading multiple digits into a single signed char in C++

Tags: c++, performance, char, cin

So I was building a silly application for an easy codeforces round and decided i wanted to spend my evening over-optimizing.

So I had the following code, where every instance of the string "signed char" was originally a "short", now the problem I am encountering is that I want to read an input using cin, number by number, and as soon as I drop to the signed char data type, cin now reads a single character at a time.

For example if the input is  (4\n33 44 11 22), cin will now set number_of_men to (4) and tmp to 4 then 3 then 3 then 4 as opposed to 33 then 44 then 11 then 22.

How do I get cin to read multiple characters of text as a number into a SINGLE signed char variable?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
signed char number_of_men;

cin >> number_of_men;
signed char tmp;
signed char max =0;
signed char  max_loc=0;
signed char min = 101;
signed char min_loc=0;

for (signed char i=0; i < number_of_men; i++) {
    cin >> tmp; 
    if(tmp > max)
    {
        max_loc = i;
        max = tmp;
    }
    if(tmp <= min)
    {
        min_loc = i;
        min = tmp;
    }
}
    cout << max_loc + number_of_men-1 -min_loc-(max_loc > min_loc)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `in C++`...so why tag `C`?

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is not a valid C program

Comment: Sorry, someone beat me to removing the tag, but why the downvotes this is still a valid question as stated

Comment: `tmp` is a char, so `cin` reads chars.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to read the integer into an actual `int` variable, and then assign its value to the `unsigned char` variable. Or you can read character by character, and use knowledge of the character encoding used to extract the digit, and use decimal arithmetic to construct the value.

Comment: @LPs I see a "signed char" as just a container of 1 byte that represents a number, is there a way to read for example (44) and dump it directly into char? I'm willing to drop cin and use scanf, or some backwards esoteric reader that supports it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would that be faster than just directly reading into a short? My end goal is to shave of whatever insignificant amount of time by reducing the size of the data type that needs to be read into

Comment: It will be faster than mocking around with characters. And if you're "over-optimizing" then you need to actually *measure* and *profile* your code. Using straight `unsigned int` for the variables compared to using e.g. `unsigned short` is going to be negligible or unmeasurable. Never optimize without measuring. And always start with the "natural" or "naive" way.

Comment: There's no way to read formatted input the way you want without first passing through a proper integer type.  @Someprogrammerdude gave you a way to do so. `fscanf` can be another "c style" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want **int8_t** from `<stdint.h>`.

`cin` determines the correct read operation based on the variable type. A char variable means you get the first character. An int variable means you get the first number.

Answer (score 1):

`cin` reads one char at a time because you're reading to a `char`, you cannot store multiple characters in a `char`, use a `string` for that. If you want to read a number and convert it to a `char`, then you need to read to an `int` value and cast to `char`:

```
int main(){
    int char_code;
    cin>>char_code;
    char c = (char)char_code;
    cout<<c;
}
```

This program would output `2` for `50`, as `50` is `2` in ASCII code (assuming you  use ASCII).