# Array input of multiple digit splliting into single digits (linear search)

Tags: c++, search

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class Linear {
  private:
    T *a;
    T key;
    int n;

  public:
    Linear();
    void LS();
};

template <class T> Linear<T>::Linear() {
    a = new T[10];
    cout << "\nEnter the no. of elements in the array";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nEnter the elements in the array";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    cout << "\nEnter the key value";
    cin >> key;
}

template <class T> void Linear<T>::LS() {
    int flag = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (key == a[i]) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) cout << "\nElement found at" << i + 1 << "index";
    else cout << "\nElement not found";
}

int main() {
    Linear<char> l;
    l.LS();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is intended to read multiple digits into the array. However when I input

> 5 23 24 25 26 27

I expect to see

> 23 24 25 26 27

but I see

> 2 3 2 4 2

Comment: Make it `Linear<int> l;` instead of `char`. Also if you are *very new to programming*, it is better to not use templates for now unless you properly understand what they are meant for, and how they work. I am flagging this as a typo as it unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @brc-dd  In fact nothing is wrong with the code ( apart from the coding style which is typical newbie stuff ) But it does work. https://godbolt.org/z/WjEErnjo7 with some small modifications to track what is going on. If something is not working then please supply all the input you give the program and provide the output of the program and also state what you expect to see if the program does not give you what you want. Learn how to use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WjEErnjo7) to create a fully working snippet with stdin and stdout.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I think you didn't read the OP's question. The [code you have written](https://godbolt.org/z/joYWdG8sj) (and what the OP has written) will not work if input is not a digit as it is reading `char` instead of `int` which can be fixed by changing the type to `int`. [Working example](https://godbolt.org/z/fPq3ozT78) (modified line 48). Moreover, instead of just printing things out it is better to use a debugger, set breakpoints and watch variables.

Comment: (1) It is not *better* to use a debugger. It is an option. I always recommend new users to get familiar with godbolt because it gives them the opportunity to provide full and working examples. If the user had provided the actual input we would be better off (2) You are right that char only selects single characters when using char. It is a bit counter intuitive that  ``cin >> a`` when ``a`` is char behaves differently that ``cin >> a`` when ``a`` is int. There are other answers touching this topic. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41609359/158285

Comment: Actually I'm still wrong. ``int8_t`` doesn't work https://godbolt.org/z/c4x9bE87d because it's effectively just an alias for ``char``  https://godbolt.org/z/c4x9bE87d

Comment: I've updated the OP's question to clarify based on @brc-dd correct observation of what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ( thanks to @brc-dd for clarifying ) is that `cin` behaves counter intuitively with regards to char types. It only reads one character at a time rather than treating char like a number which in all other respects it is. The following code demonstrates this fact

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    std::stringstream ss("27");
    int8_t v_int8;
    char v_char;
    int v_int;
    long v_long;
    short v_short;

    ss >> v_int8;
    std::cout << v_int8 << std::endl;
    ss.seekg(0);

    ss >> v_char;
    std::cout << v_char << std::endl;
    ss.seekg(0);

    ss >> v_int;
    std::cout << v_int << std::endl;
    ss.seekg(0);

    ss >> v_int;
    std::cout << v_int << std::endl;
    ss.seekg(0);

    ss >> v_short;
    std::cout << v_short << std::endl;
    ss.seekg(0);

    ss >> v_long;
    std::cout << v_long << std::endl;
    ss.seekg(0);

    
}
```

the output being

```
2
2
27
27
27
27
```

Note that even if you try to get clever and use `int8_t` it is really only an alias for `char` and will read character by character rather than as a number like you might assume.

Note: `stringstream` is like using `cin` except the input comes from a string instead of user input. `ss.seekg(0)` just puts the stream back to the beginning of the string.